# Is Batwoman self contained?

Tags: arrowverse, suggested-order, batwoman

The latest entry in *Arrowverse* universe is *Batwoman*, I wanted to jump into it but I am not up to date with Arrowverse shows. Like I have not seen Legends of Tomorrow from the last 2 seasons and Arrow's last season. So I want to know how much should I know from *Arrowverse* before jumping into *Batwoman*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I want to know how much should I know from Arrowverse before jumping into Batwoman?

**At present** (Oct 2019), Batwoman has no crossover or involvement with the rest of the Arrowverse that you need to catch up on *although* watching the original "pilot" which was the ["Elseworlds" crossover episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elseworlds_(Arrowverse)) in December 2018 which introduced that character might be useful but it's **not necessary** as it essentially takes place *after* the "origin" pilot in Episode 1 where Kate becomes Batwoman.

That's not to say that there are no plans to feature crossovers in the future but we're only 2 episodes in at the time of this answer.

Comment: We know that there will be a crossover with other series in the form of Crisis on Infinite Earths this December.

Comment: @Paulie_D You should update your answer now as there is a crossover coming up.